# Which part should the package configuration in Python script?

Tags: python, logging, configuration, config, settings

I have few code which set the configuration for logging and package setting.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Where should I put these into the script (under import, under `if __name__ == "__main__"`, etc) or can I create a configuration file for setting configuration?

```
import pybit
import pandas as pd

def get_data():
    # get data from bybit package

def data_cleaning(data):
    # using pandas for cleaning the data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = get_data()
    cleaned_data = data_cleaning(data)
```

Comment: add those after the modules import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause - you can either do it inline or via a separate function that e.g. reads a configuration file.

Re. the comment by Yoav Sheetrit - note that side effects should be avoided when doing imports, so I would recommend *not* doing these after the `import` statements.

Comment: I'm also confusing about this, from my perspective, when I import `get_data` in others script (let's say test.py), I may also want to inherit the configuration from main.py, should I use Yoav's solution or add the configuration code again in test.py.